# Best way to replicate of a group of widgets into each cell? Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a loop that I can use to populate each cell in a column with the same three widgets, stacked on top of each other and within the same cell. The best way I can think of doing this is to first create a frame for each cell (via a loop) then to populate each frame with three widgets (via a separate loop). The top & bottom widgets will be buttons, and the middle widget will be a label.

Would this be a good approach, or can you suggest something cleaner?

### Simplified code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog,filedialog,colorchooser,messagebox,Frame,Button
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import textwrap

root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
rq = 10 # row quantity

canv_1 = tk.Canvas(root, bg="blue")
canv_1.pack(side="top", fill="both")#, fill="both", expand=True)

canv_2 = tk.Canvas(root, bg="gray")
canv_2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

frame = tk.Frame(canv_2)

# create, bind & position scrollbar
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(canv_2, orient="vertical", command=canv_2.yview)
canv_2.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

canv_2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canv_2.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canv_2=canv_2: onFrameConfigure(canv_2))

labels = ["","Chapter Title", "Slide", "Instructions"]
ColWidths = [5, 15, 15, 40]
root.label_wid = []
font1 = ("arial", 15)

load1 = Image.open("StartingImage.jpg")
root.render1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)

ch_text = []

for i in range(len(labels)):
    root.label_wid.append(tk.Label(canv_1,
                                   font=font1,
                                   relief="raised",
                                   text=labels[i],
                                   width=ColWidths[i],
                                   ).grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="we"))

c1 = "#a9d08e"
c2 = "#8dd1bf"

Move_col = [
    tk.Entry(
        frame,
        bg = c1,
        width = ColWidths[0],
        font = font1)
    for y in range(0, rq)
]

Title_col = [
    tk.Entry(
        frame,
        bg = c1,
        width = ColWidths[1],
        font = font1)
    for y in range(0, rq)
]

Slide_col = [
    tk.Entry(
        frame,
        bg = c2,
        width = ColWidths[2],
        font = font1)
    for y in range(0, rq)
]

instruction_col = [
    tk.Text(
        frame,
        bg="white",
        wrap="word",
        font=font1, width = ColWidths[3], height=10)
    for y in range(0, rq)
]

for y in range(0, rq):
    Move_col[y].grid(row=y + 1, column=0, sticky='news')
    Title_col[y].grid(row=y + 1, column=1, sticky='news')
    Slide_col[y].grid(row=y + 1, column=2, sticky='news')
    instruction_col[y].grid(row=y+1, column=3, sticky='news')

bt1 = tk.Button(canv_1, text="Export", font=font1, bg="#f5b942")
bt1.grid(row=0, column=4)
load2 = Image.open("scroll-up-gray.png")
root.render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load2)
load3 = Image.open("scroll-down.png")
root.render3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load3)

root.mainloop()
```

### Output:

[image]

### Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a class that inherits from the `Frame` widget. You can then use instances of this class almost like any other widget. I say "almost" because it doesn't support all of the same options as the built-in widgets, but it behaves the same way: you can create it, destroy it, and call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on it.

There are many ways to do it. The following example uses text instead of images for the button to keep the example simple:

```
class MoveWidget(tk.Frame):
    """
    Custom widget with buttons for moving up and down. When clicked,
    the button will call the given command with two parameters: the
    index and either "up" or "down"
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, bg, index, command):
        super().__init__(parent, background=bg)

        self.index = index
        self.command = command

        self.up_button = tk.Button(self, text="^", bg=bg, command=self.up)
        self.down_button = tk.Button(self, text="v", bg=bg, command=self.down)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, bg=bg, text=str(index))

        self.up_button.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.down_button.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def up(self):
        self.command(self.index, "up")

    def down(self):
        self.command(self.index, "down")
```

Before you can use this class you need to define a function to move the item. Have it accept an index and a direction. The actual implementation is up to you, this is good enough for this answer:

```
    def move(index, direction):
        if direction == "up":
            print(f"Moving index {index} up")
        else:
            print(f"Moving index {index} down")
```

Now you can create an instance of the class, giving it the parent widget, index, command, and color as parameters:

```
Move_col = [
    MoveWidget(
        frame,
        bg=c1,
        index=y,
        command=move)
    for y in range(0, rq)
]
```

You don't have to change the code that calls `grid` on this widget.